# ExecutorService argument to SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, executorservice, swingworker

I have an abstract class extending `SwingWorker` called `FetchWorker` to do some background data fetching and modifying the data that is fetched for my application. In my `FetchWorker` is an inner class of `StatisticLayerController`. This StatisticLayerController is extended by two classes. I initialize new threads within my `FetchWorker` to do some calculations. I used to use the ExecutorService of `TrackHistoryLayerController.`

Like below:

```
public class TrackHistoryLayerController extends StatisticLayerController
{
   private final ExecutorService heatMapAdderExecutor;
   ...

   public AdsbFetchWorker(...)  extends FetchWorker
   {
      super(...);
   }

   @Override
   protected final List<ADSBTrack> doInBackground() throws Exception
   {
      filtered.forEach( track -> {
         this.heatMapAdderExecutor.submit( new HeatmapAdderHelper( ... ) );
      } );
      while ( this.latch.getCount() != 0 )
      {
         this.publishValue( ( int ) this.latch.getCount() );
      }
      this.latch.await();
      this.publishValue( ( int ) this.latch.getCount() );
      if ( this.createImage() )
      {
         this.placeImage();
      }
      return filtered;
   }
}
```

So in this case `HeatMapAdderHelper` is my Helper thread which does some calculation for me. It was all working and all was fine.
But now I wanted to change class structure a bit more, I wanted to make my `Controller` class `abstract` and I no longer wanted my `Worker` classes to be an inner class.

---

My question is, I cannot(should not) create `ExecutorService` within a `Worker` since the worker is going to be initialized each time event is invoked. Only thing I could do would be passing the ExecutorService from the `Controller` as an argument to the `SwingWorker` but would that be a good practice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a `static` executor or a singleton instance?

Comment: @daniu You mean within the worker right? But then Do not I have one ExecutorService for all of the controllers?

Comment: Yes, you do. But do keep in mind that an `ExecutorService` is a wrapper that manages threads which are a global resource; it makes sense to manage them globally (and have only few of them). You don't get more performance magically by just adding threads (or `ExecutorService`s, for that matter).

Comment: @daniu So what you are saying is that having `ExecutorService` for each `Controller` **does not** provide me some extra performance than having **just one** `ExecutorService` for all `Controllers`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Having 4 `ExecutorService`s with 1 thread each and having 1 `ExecutorService` with 1 thread are essentially the same performance-wise - however the latter will probably be better distributing the work.

Comment: @daniu Alright, thank you for the suggestion I will try to do in that way and see if I face any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course also just use the default `ExecutorService` provided by `CompletableFuture` by doing

```
filtered.forEach( track -> {
     CompletableFuture.runAsync(new HeatmapAdderHelper( ... ) );
  } );
```

As a side note, this

```
  while ( this.latch.getCount() != 0 )
  {
     this.publishValue( ( int ) this.latch.getCount() );
  }
  this.latch.await();
  this.publishValue( ( int ) this.latch.getCount() );
```

looks very dodgy... a busy loop while waiting for the results? Also, why do you `await` the latch after you already waited in the loop? Assuming the latch is a `CountDownLatch`.

I'm sure if you provided even more context, we could give a better overall solution.

It looks like you can just do something like

```
CompletableFuture<Void>[] futures = 
     filtered.stream().map(t -> new HeatmapAdderHelper(t))
                 .map(CompletableFuture::runAsync)
                 .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).andThen(createImage());
```

Or with a `CountDownLatch`:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(filtered.size());
filtered.forEach(f -> {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(new HeatmapAdderHelper(f))
                     .thenRun(latch::countDown);
});
latch.await();
createImage();
```

Comment: I think I was a bit careless not to see that `while-loop` problem, it was just intended to view the progress, thank you for pointing out, I will modify it. Although I am really not familiar with `CompletableFuture`, in fact I never used it before. In this case how is it different from the `ExecutorService` ? Does it have initial pool size?

Comment: @Bleach A `CompletableFuture` is a result that is being calculated concurrently; it implements the `Future` interface (you get one of those when you `submit()` a `Callable` to an `ExecutorService`. The `CompletableFuture#runAsync` is pretty much just a convenience method to run something in the background without taking care of an `ExecutorService` to manage the threads.

Comment: I modified my code in the way you wrote. But I notice everytime I click on my button to calculate, just one of the threads are gets running in JVM, like in the photo in [this photo](https://imgur.com/a/wP6S9rH) Is that normal?

Comment: @Bleach I really can't tell you that; you might want to look into why the other threads are sleeping/locked etc.